# Parse resource in d3.queue

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, text-parsing

I am using d3.queue to load two different resources before drawing a visualization.

If the resources do not need to be parsed, the task can be achieved pretty easily:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.text, 'file1.txt')
  .defer(d3.json, 'file2.json')
  .await(draw);
```

Now, suppose that `file.txt` has the following structure:

```
STATE|STUSAB|STATE_NAME|STATENS
01|AL|Alabama|01779775
02|AK|Alaska|01785533
04|AZ|Arizona|01779777
```

I know I can use `d3.dsvFormat('|')` to parse this file, but how can I do it in a queue?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackdbd/p3dg4wr6/)

The file I am using can be found here: [National FIPS and GNIS Codes File](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the [`d3-request`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) code and I implemented a function that loads and parses a pipe-separated .txt file. It's basically the same code of [`json.js`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/src/json.js).

```
import * as d3RequestType from '../../node_modules/d3-request/src/type';

const d3Psv = d3RequestType.default('text/plain', (xhr) => {
  const psv = d3.dsvFormat('|');
    return psv.parse(xhr.responseText);
});

const queue = d3.queue();
queue
  .defer(d3Psv, 'file1.txt')
  .defer(d3.json, 'file2.json')
  .await(draw);
```

In another project I had to load a file where the values were separated with semicolons and I used the same approach.

Note that you can also pass a rowFunction as the second argument of `psv.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that parsing in a deferred tasked like you do e.g. for `d3.json` as there is no convenience method for requesting and parsing your content at once. When dealing with delimiter separated values D3 offers convenience methods for only the comma ([`d3.csv`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#csv)) and tabs ([`d3.tsv`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#tsv)). These will request the resource **and** parse the contents in a single run. The `await` callback will then be called with the already parsed contents.

Since you are using a different delimiter, namely a pipe `"|"` character, you will have to do these two steps one after the other. In a queue you can still use [`d3.text`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#text) to request the textual contents of your file. The parsing, however, will have to be done in the `await` callback by using [`d3.dsvFormat("|").parse`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse). The necessary pieces are already contained in your code; you just have to use `psv` to do the parsing in your `draw()` function:

```
const psv = d3.dsvFormat('|');

const draw = (error, data1, data2) => {
  console.log(psv.parse(data1));         // Do the parsing in await
  console.log(data2);
}

const queue = d3.queue();
queue
  .defer(d3.text, url1)                  // Load textual contents
  .defer(d3.json, url2)
  .await(draw);
```

Have a look at the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q4hhbn9/) for a working example.